# Where do I find Apache error logs for sites that I installed with buildkit?

Tags: developer, civicrm-buildkit

I installed a site with [buildkit](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit). Now I'm doing some dev work which is producing WSOD / 500 / "Internal Server Error" errors, but I can't find any logs about these errors.

I've looked in `/var/log/apache2/` and don't see any recent logs there. Is there somewhere else that the log messages are going?

Answer (score 2):

Buildkit uses [amp](https://github.com/amp-cli/amp) to install sites which means you have to look in `~/.amp`. Log files are in `~/.amp/log` and separated by site.